# How to use PHP mail function without leaving the actual page it's called from

Tags: php, html, email, forms, dynamic

I am using an html sign up form for a website I'm building. The form accepts first name, last name, email address, birthdate (month,day,year), and sex. It calls a php file to process the results and email them to me like this:

```
<form  method="post" action="sendMail.php" >
```

the php file looks like:

```
<?php
$firstName = $_REQUEST['FirstName'] ;
$lastName = $_REQUEST['LastName'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['EmailAddress'] ;
$birthdate = $_REQUEST['month'] ;
$sex = $_REQUEST['sex'] ;

$message .=  "First Name: \t";
$message  = $firstName;
$message .= "\n";
$message .=  "Last Name: \t";
$message .= $lastName;
$message .= "\n";
$message .=  "Email: \t";
$message .= $email;
$message .= "\n";
$message .=  "Birthdate: \t";
$message .= $birthdate;
$message .= "\n";
$message .=  "Sex: \t";
$message .= $sex;

mail( "ty@ollielifestyle.com", "Sign-Up Form Results", $message, "From: $email" );
/*?>  header( "Location: http://www.example.com/thankyou.html" );
<?php */
?>
```

The script works fine to process and email the results, but I do not know how to make the 'php mail() function' return to the exact same calling page. I know that typically people like to show a thank you page but I do not want to lead the visitor to just a thank you page. Is there a way to alter the 'php mail() function' to redirect to the same exact page that called it, or to call it without leaving the page in the first place? Thanks for any hints in advance!

**Update** I have included the php into the same page with the sign up form. It isn't returning any errors but I do not seem to be getting any emails delivered to the gmail account I set up for it. I did not know if it would work better to place the form in the html file as I normally would (outside of the php function) or inside an else statement so I tried it both ways with neither giving an email. Was there a logical error in the code below ?

Version 1:

```
$message .=  "First Name: \t";
$message  = $firstName;
$message .= "\n";
$message .=  "Last Name: \t";
$message .= $lastName;
$message .= "\n";
$message .=  "Email: \t";
$message .= $email;
$message .= "\n";
$message .=  "Birthdate: \t";
$message .= $birthdate;
$message .= "\n";
$message .=  "Sex: \t";
$message .= $sex;

mail( "ymaxwell86@gmail.com", "Sign-Up Form Results", $message, "From: $email" );  
echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
}
?>
```

First Name:*       
                   

             Last Name:*        
             
             
             Email Address:* 
             
             
             
             Birthday:    
             
               Month
               January
               February
               March
               April
               May
               June
               July
               August
               September
               October
               November
               December
             
             
               Day
             
             
               Year
             
             
    function changeDate(i){
    var e = document.getElementById('day');
    while(e.length>0)
    e.remove(e.length-1);
    var j=-1;
    if(i=="na")
    k=0;
    else if(i==2)
    k=28;
    else if(i==4||i==6||i==9||i==11)
    k=30;
    else
    k=31;
    while(j++1909){
    var s = document.createElement('option');
    var e = document.getElementById('year');
    s.text=y;
    s.value=y;
    try{
    e.add(s,null);}
    catch(ex){
    e.add(s);}}

Gender:               
              Male
              Female
             
           
             *required fields

Version 2:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
  {
  //send email
  $firstName = $_REQUEST['FirstName'] ;
  $lastName = $_REQUEST['LastName'] ;
  $email = $_REQUEST['EmailAddress'] ;
  $birthdate = $_REQUEST['month'] ;
  $sex = $_REQUEST['sex'] ;

  $message .=  "First Name: \t";
  $message  = $firstName;
  $message .= "\n";
  $message .=  "Last Name: \t";
  $message .= $lastName;
  $message .= "\n";
  $message .=  "Email: \t";
  $message .= $email;
  $message .= "\n";
  $message .=  "Birthdate: \t";
  $message .= $birthdate;
  $message .= "\n";
  $message .=  "Sex: \t";
  $message .= $sex;

  mail( "ymaxwell86@gmail.com", "Sign-Up Form Results", $message, "From: $email" );  
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
  }
else
//if "email" is not filled out, display the form
  {
  echo "<form action=''  method='post'>
       <p>First Name:* &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
         <input name='FirstName' type='text' id='FirstName' size='25' />&nbsp; &nbsp;<br />

         Last Name:*&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <input name='LastName' type='text' id='LastName' size='25'/><br />
         <br />
         Email Address:*&nbsp;
         <input name='EmailAddress' type='text' id='EmailAddress' size='25' onblur='valid_email=validateEmail(email_field,mandatory,messages);' />
         <br />
         <br />
         Birthday: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <select name='month' onChange='changeDate(this.options[selectedIndex].value);'>
           <option value='na'>Month</option>
           <option value='1'>January</option>
           <option value='2'>February</option>
           <option value='3'>March</option>
           <option value='4'>April</option>
           <option value='5'>May</option>
           <option value='6'>June</option>
           <option value='7'>July</option>
           <option value='8'>August</option>
           <option value='9'>September</option>
           <option value='10'>October</option>
           <option value='11'>November</option>
           <option value='12'>December</option>
         </select>
         <select name='day' id='day'>
           <option value='na'>Day</option>
         </select>
         <select name='year' id='year'>
           <option value='na'>Year</option>
         </select>
         <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
function changeDate(i){
var e = document.getElementById('day');
while(e.length>0)
e.remove(e.length-1);
var j=-1;
if(i=='na')
k=0;
else if(i==2)
k=28;
else if(i==4||i==6||i==9||i==11)
k=30;
else
k=31;
while(j++<k){
var s=document.createElement('option');
var e=document.getElementById('day');    
if(j==0){
s.text='Day';
s.value='na';    
try{
e.add(s,null);}
catch(ex){
e.add(s);}}
else{
s.text=j;
s.value=j;
try{
e.add(s,null);}
catch(ex){
e.add(s);}}}}
y = 2010;
while (y-->1909){
var s = document.createElement('option');
var e = document.getElementById('year');
s.text=y;
s.value=y;
try{
e.add(s,null);}
catch(ex){
e.add(s);}}
</script>
         <br />
       </p>
       <p>Gender:  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
         <input type='radio' name='sex' value='male' /> Male
         <input type='radio' name='sex' value='female' /> Female
         <br />
       <div id='mailListNote'>
         *required fields
       </div>
         <br />
  <br />

         &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
         <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' onclick='valid_email =validateEmail(email_field,mandatory,messages); '/>
         &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
         <INPUT TYPE=RESET  onClick='return confirm('Are you sure you want to reset the form?')'>
       </p>
     </form>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Note: I'm very much aware that I have not added the necessary protection from php email injection or even error checking to make sure the values exist before they are stored in the variable $message and emailed. I will add in the error checking as the last step.

Comment: Why do you need the header at all? If you just call `mail` at the top of the file, won't it load the rest of the page normally?

Comment: Are you trying to redirect, so as to protect the post from a refresh, but you'd like to do this for a variable number of pages?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc You're right I actually didn't need the header and ended up taking it out. I originally left it in because I read somewhere that the php mail() would return an error without it.

Comment: @sdleihssirch No i wasn't trying to protect the post from a refresh through a redirect. I was originally trying to call the php mail (in a seperate) file from the sign up form and remain on the page containing the sign up form. I thought the best way was to redirect back to that page through the header but have found more appropriate ways to have the visitor remain on that page through ajax. Since the form is on multiple pages (7) it works out better to use this code: <html> 
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically two options:

- Simply change the url in `header("location:…");` to return to the original page.
- Or use Ajax to submit the form in the background. There are plenty helpful plugins based on JQuery. [Google is your friend.](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=jquery+ajax+form+submit&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

It is definitely a good idea to provide some feedback to the user after submitting your form. So, the thank you page might just be the most user-friendly solution. And even the technically easiest solution for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @sprain.! For a quick fix I inserted the url in the header. I am experimenting with a few of the solutions I found on google. Instead of using an entirely different thank you page. I am going to use a function to display a thank you message inside the form box rather than directing to another page.

Answer (score 3):

Use ajax to send the mail without leaving the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a blank action, and the form will submit to the same URL that it's hosted on, like so:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your form page is coded, you could put the exact PHP you listed in your question at the top of the form page itself and wrap it in an 'if' statement that determines if the the form is being submitted. e.g.:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['EmailAddress'])) { /** your code here **/}
```

Then you would have the form submit as mentioned in a previous answer.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

This way, you could use the same if statement to display feedback or a thank you of some kind.  To take this even further, this approach easily allows you to provide errors in the event that the submitted data fails your validation process.

Comment: I have included the php into the same page with the sign up form. It isn't returning any errors but I do not seem to be getting any emails delivered to the gmail account I set up for it. I did not know if it would work better to place the form in the html file as I normally would (outside of the php function) or inside an else statement so I tried it both ways with neither giving an email. Any ideas?

Comment: In Version 2 above, it appears that you are using `isset($_REQUEST['email'])` as your test condition, but I don't see that your form is sending a field named 'email'.  Perhaps you meant to use `isset($_REQUEST['EmailAddress'])` as your if condition?

Comment: Also, if you echo some sort of feedback at the beginning of your if segment you will be able to see if your condition passed or not.  Another thing to keep in mind is that if you are on a shared server, they will often require that your email 'from' address matches the domain name of your account.